# Servo motor driver - 12V to 0~10v

Tags: resistors, potentiometer, servo

I have a servo motor and it's driver
I wired up everything and it's almost working. 
The driver generate a 12V signal and I control the motor with 0~10V analog command.

I started from the point 5mA was enough as a command, hence I used a 400ohms resistor to drop the voltage from 12 to 10V 
Then I calculated I need a 2KOhm potentiometer to be able to adjust from 0V to 10V
I wired evething such as the picture. But at the end I got 12V to 2V when I adjust the potentiometer, I can't go below 2V. And normally I should get 10V to 0V

What is wrong with my setup? [image]

Comment: Your sketch shows the pot output as +/- 10 V which means an output from -10 V to +10 V which is impossible with only a positive supply. It should read 0 - 10 V.

Comment: Exactly. I did showed my switch which invert the two. Wires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3FIZv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) What you want. (b) What you appear to have done.*

- (a) gives 0 to 10 V.
- (b) gives 2 to 12 V.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I applied the same rule as amp are the same in the whole circuit... But not the voltage ;) dummy thing as usual